# Turning Off SPC card on Juniper SRX5800 series Firewall

Tags: firewall, juniper-srx, hardware, srx, line-card

We are running SRX5800 in a cluster. Each Node has FPCs as well as SPCs installed. Due to some maintenance downtime , we were required to power off FPCs as well as SPCs on a backup node , not in a whole cluster.

Considering the fact that Node 1 (SRX5-2) is the active firewall for both redundancy groups and Node 0 (SRX5-1) is the backup firewall , we used the command `'request chassis fpc slot 0 node 0 offline' on active firewall. This command ran well and FPC went offline. The FPC model is SRX5k DPC 4X 10GE.

When we used the same command i.e. `'request chassis fpc slot 7 node 0 offline'` to power off the SPC , however it didn't went offline. Having said that , SPC is installed in slot 7 position of Node 0 and the SPC model is SRX5k SPC.

```
user@SRX5-2> request chassis fpc slot 7 node 0 offline 
node0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Offline command not supported for FPC in slot 7
```

====================================================================

```
user@SRX5-2> show chassis cluster status 
Cluster ID: 1 
Node                  Priority          Status    Preempt  Manual failover

Redundancy group: 0 , Failover count: 1
    node0                   200         primary        no       no  
    node1                   100         secondary      no       no  

Redundancy group: 1 , Failover count: 3
    node0                   255         primary        no       yes 
    node1                   100         secondary      no       yes
```

Based on the above output , is it possible to turn off the SPC card in a SRX5800 series firewall or SPC card can't be turned off.

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you add "show chassis cluster status" please?

Comment: @JordanHead. Sure I have added the output in the the question body.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That would appear to be the case. [Juniper's documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/hardware/srx5800/topics/topic-map/srx5800-maintaining-line-cards-modules.html#id-replacing-spcs-in-an-operating-srx5400-srx5600-or-srx5800-services-gateways-chassis-cluster) only shows a full chassis shutdown when messing with an SPC. (shutdown and power off the standby unit.)